# Java - Do object references get destroyed when the creating class is closed?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection, jvm

Say i have a class, which loads a file and then calls another method to do something to that file. For example, counting the words in the file.

Within class CountWords, a number of objects/collections are created in order to get the number of words. The method runs, the number of words is found, and then this is returned to the calling class.

My question is, do all the objects/collection created in the CountWords class get "destroyed" when control is returned to the calling class or do they remain in the memory? If the latter, would i have to set each object to null before exiting the class to mark them for collection?

Comment: You want to read about [Java garbage collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't generally control exactly when a Java object gets destroyed.  It will get destroyed some time after it becomes inaccessible - in other words, when there are no further references to it in any scope.

If you create an object, and store a reference to it in a field of another object, then the object you created continues to be accessible for as long as the object that has the reference to it is accessible.

If you have code like this

```
public void run() {
    Foo a = new Foo();
    System.out.println("This method is finished");
}
```

then the `Foo` that you created will be inaccessible as soon as `run` finishes, because there are no more variables with references to it.  `Foo` will be destroyed some time afterwards.  Unless of course, the constructor of `Foo` does some magic to register itself in some nasty `static` data store somewhere.

So in general, you don't need to go round setting references to null to destroy objects.  From the point of view of the garbage collector, letting those references go out of scope is just as good as setting them to null.

Comment: There is at least one exception: if an object is only referenced by [`WeakReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and [`PhantomReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) (though `PhantomReference`s do not really reference the object), it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @Turing85 That's absolutely true.  I guess I wanted to avoid some of the nasty detail, but I shouldn't have sacrificed correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a programming language that has memory management aka garbage collection. The basic answer is, the garbage collector will take care of reclaiming the memory of unused objects.

But since you have tagged the question with `[garbage-collection]`, you should already know this. So it’s not clear what additional detail you want to know or why you think your scenario is special in any way, to deserve an additional answer beyond “there is a garbage collector”.

You question is full of phrases that are wrong or misguiding.

- “*do object references get destroyed*”—the storage of *objects* is reclaimed, there is no such thing as “destruction of references”
- “*when the creating class is closed*”—there is no such thing as “closing of classes”
- “*do all the objects/collection created in the CountWords class get ‘destroyed’ when control is returned to the calling class or do they remain in the memory?*”—in this form, not simple to answer

  - there is no such thing as “destruction”. The whole purpose of garbage collection is to permit the reuse of the memory. This implies recording somewhere that the memory is free. But the memory itself does not need to be touched.
  - when your method returns, these objects are *eligible* for garbage collection. The garbage collection itself does not have to run immediately. It may happen when there is need for free memory or when the CPU load is low.
  - As said, even if the garbage collector ran, the result is that the memory is now considered to be free, not necessarily to “scrub” the memory. So the objects *may* “remain in the memory” until actually being overwritten by other objects. So that’s simply the wrong question. You actually want to know whether the memory will be reusable.
- “*If the latter, would i have to set each object to null before exiting the class to mark them for collection?*”—“the latter” still implies that the memory is free, semantically. But what do you want to “set to `null`”? The references do not exist anymore. The objects are unreachable.

  The answer is there is nothing you can do and there is nothing you should do. That’s the whole point of garbage collection, no need for you to do anything.

Comment: While i appreciate all replies i get on Stack Overflow, i was a little bit miffed by your reply in particular. It's clear from my reputation that i'm a amateur programmer, so it's not inconceivable i'd be asking questions from an amateurs perspective. Again, thank you for your reply, but next time be a bit more gentle with newbies - remember you were one once!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your knowledge nor you being a beginner. It’s about asking a precise question. As said, you obviously know about the existence of the garbage collector as displayed by tagging your question right. We can’t guess which facts you know and what is unclear to you, so you have to clarify it in your question. By the way, the Stackoverflow reputation doesn’t say anything about your programming skills, only about your history on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to set the objects to null after coming out the function . For this Java have garbage Collector ,  which runs on the Java Virtual Machine which gets rid of objects which are not being used by a Java application anymore. It is a form of automatic memory management.

For example :

```
for (int i =0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    String s = String.valueOf(i)
}
```

In the above code, the integer s is being created on each iteration of the for loop. This means that in every iteration, a little bit of memory is being allocated to make a integer object.

Going back to the code, we can see that once a single iteration is executed, in the next iteration, the integer object that was created in the previous iteration is not being used anymore -- that object is now considered "garbage".

Eventually, we'll start getting a lot of garbage, and memory will be used for objects which aren't being used anymore. If this keeps going on, eventually the Java Virtual Machine will run out of space to make new objects.

That's where the garbage collector steps in.

The garbage collector will look for objects which aren't being used anymore, and gets rid of them, freeing up the memory so other new objects can use that piece of memory.

Automatic memory management schemes like garbage collection makes it so the programmer does not have to worry so much about memory management issues, so he or she can focus more on developing the applications they need to develop.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is quite correct.  An `int` is _not_ an object.  The `int` variable `s` in your example isn't on the heap, so it's not garbage collected.  It simply ceases to exist when it goes out of scope.

Comment: The answer would be perfectly correct if the loop body were something like `String s = String.valueOf(i)`.